# What meta data is handled by Gmail?

Tags: gmail, metadata

Does Gmail detect any sort of meta data (e.g. microformats, microdata, RDFa, etc)? If so, which and how does it handle it?

Comment: You mean like embedded vCards and stuff? Or special headers? Or parsing text to make sense of it (like phone numbers)?

Comment: I was thinking about something like microdata, microformats, RDFa, that kind of stuff. Thanks for the asking, I'll edit the question above.